# Django, Direction of ManyToMany relations

Tags: django-models

I can't find the logic to which of the two related models should have the M2M field?  Here is an example from the Django tutorial

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

what difference would it make if I define the M2M field in Person instead of Group ?

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can add a `ManyToManyField` on either model and get equivalent results, so the decision usually comes down to which model it makes more sense in, and that's usually a very subjective decision.

I usually decide by determining which model the relationship is more integral to: is the set of members more important to a `Group` than the set of groups is to the `Person`? If so, the relationship field should go on the `Group` model.

Comment: One of my models is User and so although it's a set of objects a user has, it's easier to modify the new model than the User. Is that a good reason to do that ?

Comment: @Kiarash, yes, that's another good point.  If you're dealing with a model built into Django or provided by a 3rd party app that you don't want to change, practicality beats everything and you should add the relationship where its convenient.